# Why does `x_\text y` work?

Tags: tex-core, syntax

As far as I have understand the tokenization in LaTeX, `x_\text y` will be split up into

1. `x`
2. `_`
3. `\text`
4. `y`

Now the `_` will consume/bind to the next token. However, `\text` takes an argument as well. If `_` consumes `\text`, the latter does not have an argument.

When I do something like `\frac 1 \sqrt 2`, it does not work in contrast to the first one, and this is the behavior that I would except.

Why does the first example work at all?

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right of course! I deleted my comment. It is expanded before it is sent to "TeX's stomach" according to TeXbook. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @HenriMenke As you see from my answer, it's a bit more complex. ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to know that `_` (in math mode, of course, and with normal setting of category codes) will expand the next token in order to see if a brace (explicit or implicit) follows. This is common for primitives that want a `<general text>` as their argument (so also `\uppercase`, for instance).

Thus `_` will try expanding the following token, because it's not `{` or `\bgroup`. The first level expansion of `\text` is

```
\protect\text•
```

(where `•` denotes a space in the name of the control sequence). Since we are in a normal situation (typesetting), `\protect` is equivalent to `\relax`. Here another feature comes in: when a `<general text>` is being looked for, spaces and `\relax` tokens are ignored (they're called a `<filler>` in the TeXbook), so this `\protect` disappears. Now `\text•` is not a brace, so TeX continues expanding it; the first level expansion is

```
\ifmmode\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi
```

OK, we're in math mode, so we're left with

```
\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi
```

Hmm, `\expandafter` is not a brace, expand it! This causes the expansion of `\else`, therefore just `\text@` remains. Here we are, almost! The definition of `\text@` in `amstext.sty` is

```
\def\text@#1{{\mathchoice
  {\textdef@\displaystyle\f@size{#1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\f@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\sf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle \ssf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  \check@mathfonts
  }%
}
```

so, since TeX wants to expand it, the argument is looked for; `y` is a token which is not a brace that delimits an argument, so it ***is*** the argument.

The expansion is then

```
{\mathchoice...}
```

with `y` in place of `#1`. Hurray! The open brace has been found! Go on and typeset the subscript.

Final word: always use braces around the subscript and arguments; your input will be clearer. So

```
$x_{\text{y}}$
```

and nothing else.

Comment: Assuming of course that `_` is not an active token actually absorbing an argument!

Comment: @JosephWright I've added that I assume `_` has the usual category code.

Comment: Thanks for blowing my mind. I only had a *hunch* that TeX would have a “Alice in Wonderland” experience in store for me so far …

Comment: @queueoverflow Did you like the `<filler>` part?

Comment: So far, everything that has an `@` lets me think about it being internal and that I do not need to think about it, if I just want to use it. Kind of like assembly language. I just had no idea that there are so many layers of expansion to it.

Comment: @queueoverflow take a small document and add `\tracingall` and see the expansions logged in the log file. (don't use a beamer document unless you have a big disk:-)

Answer (score 5):

`\text` is defined in `amstext.sty` by means of `\text@` where

```
\text@ #1->{\mathchoice{...}\check@mathfonts}
```

which adds braces around its expansion text. Thus the braces from the expansion of `\text@` will enclose all stuff in the index.

Compare for instance:

```
\def\bad#1{\rm #1}
\def\good#1{{\rm #1}}
% $x_\bad y$% <- Missing { inserted
$x_\good y$
\bye
```

Comment: So `\text` is handled before `_` is?

Comment: Okay, the answer from @egreg makes it clear now.