# Bookmarking uppercase Roman numbers

Tags: bookmarks, roman-numerals

Have the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=page,hypertexnames]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec. \RNum{1}}
    \section{Sec. \RNum{2}}
\end{document}
```

The bookmark in the PDF shows that the numbers are indeed small case (while it should be upper case). How to get it fixed?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you provide the section numbers manually? Is it just for the MWE (if so, that is perfectly valid of course)?

Comment: @Marijn Actually, in my case, section names are, *Type I*, *Type II* etc. So, I have to write Roman numerals in section name.

Comment: I guess you'd need an expandable `\uppercase`, but `\uupercase` is not expandable, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387816/35864. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10805/35864

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\RNum}{m}{\int_to_Roman:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{1}}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{2}}
\end{document}` seems to work.

Comment: Or from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23492/35864 without LaTeX3 `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\RNum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{1}}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{2}}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an expandable version of `\RNum` so that it appears correctly in the bookmarks. But `\uppercase` is not expandable (see [\expandafter with \uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387816/35864)), so you will need the slightly different definition from the LaTeX kernel (see also [How can I get Roman numerals in text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23487/35864), thank you to [Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%c3%bcger) for pointing out that the initial answer had just a verbatim copy of `\RNum`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\RNum}{} % empty def to throw error if name already taken
\let\RNum\@Roman      % actual definition
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{1}}
    \section{Sec.\ \RNum{2}}
\end{document}
```

[image: The bookmarks sidebar shows "Sec. I" and "Sec. II"]