# Upper-case programmatic data with expl3 in TeX Live 2019

Tags: expansion, plain-tex, latex3

I use the following expl3 code to upper-case the first character of a programmatic string. The code is from the body of a control sequence definition and is not supposed to be fully expandable.

```tex
\tl_set:Nn
  \l_tmpa_tl
  { \str_uppercase:n { #1 } }

\tl_set:Nx
  \l_tmpb_tl
  {
    \tl_head:f { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_tail:n { #1 }
  }
```

However, I need my code to work with TeX Live 2019 and the `\str_uppercase:n` control sequence is unavailable in TeX Live 2019. Since I know that `#1` will only contain ASCII letters, I assumed that I would be able to substitute `\str_uppercase:n` with `\uppercase`. However, `\uppercase` seems to defy expansion, so `\tl_head:f { \l_tmpa_tl }` will produce the `\uppercase` token rather than the first uppercase character.

Comment: the uppercasing code has been available for longer than that, possibly originally in package form, Joseph can answer the deails:-)

Comment: That would be useful, although I should mention that this is plain TeX code, i.e. `expl3-generic.tex`, not LaTeX. Therefore, LaTeX packages are unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, `\uppercase` seems to defy expansion, so `\tl_head:f { \l_tmpa_tl }` will produce the \uppercase token rather than the first uppercase character.

That is because the `\uppercase` primitive is unexpandable and processed by the execution processor rather than the expansion processor, see also [`\expandafter` with `\uppercase`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387819/70941).

> I need my code to work with TeX Live 2019 and the `\str_uppercase:n` control sequence is unavailable in TeX Live 2019.

According to [the LaTeX 3 newsletter from November 2016](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3news10.pdf), the `\str_upper_case:n` command has been available since TeX Live 2017. In 2020, it has been renamed to `\str_uppercase:n` and [deprecated](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/l3kernel/doc/l3obsolete.txt). However, the deprecated command `\str_upper_case:n` is still available.