# How to Capitalize Symbol in Glossary Print only using a New Entry Field?

Tags: beamer, symbols, glossaries, capitalization, glossaries-extra

How can I forced the Symbol to be printed in capitalized form or full uppercase in the glossary print only (with non capitalized form declared in the field `symbol`)?

The best solution for me would be to have like a new field `symbolname` when declaring a new glossary entry, this field will be used by LaTeX for printing the symbol in the glossary print only. The symbol declared in the field `symbol` will be used in the document text only. In other words, I would like to have - for `symbol` field -, the same result given when I use the `name` field and the `text` field, which permits to dissociate the use in glossary print from the use in text...

Here a MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={4}}
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
  name={Compressor},
  text={compressor},
  sort={compressor},
  description={Air Compressor},
  symbol={cp},
  parent=subsytem
}
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
  name={Compressor Motor},
  sort={compressor motor},
  text={compressor motor},
  description={Motor of the \Gls{compressor}},
  symbol={cm},
  parent=subsytem
}


\begin{document}
\gls{compressor_motor}
\gls{compressor}
\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Instead of this result :

[image]

I would like something like that ("Compressor (Cp)" instead of "Compressor (cp)" and "Compressor Motor (CM)" instead of "Compressor Motor (cm)") :

[image]

But again, I would like the symbol to be declared in lowercase in the symbol field (cp or cm) as shown in the **non-working** exemple below :

```
\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={4}}
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
  name={Compressor},
  text={compressor},
  sort={compressor},
  description={Air Compressor},
  symbolname={Cp},%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  symbol={cp},
  parent=subsytem
}
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
  name={Compressor Motor},
  sort={compressor motor},
  text={compressor motor},
  description={Motor of the \Gls{compressor}},
  symbolname={CM},%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  symbol={cm},
  parent=subsytem
}
\begin{document}
\gls{compressor_motor}
\gls{compressor}
\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

---

**Why I want lowercase in `symbol` field?**

Because I use the lowercase symbol form to declare other "math entries" like below the use of `\glssymbol{compressor}` in the `name` field:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newglossaryentry{PQ}{name={Physical Quantities},description={\glspar},sort={5}}
\newglossaryentry{Qcp}
{
  name={$\mathbf{\bm{Q}}_{\glssymbol{compressor},out}$},
  sort={Qcpout},
  text={\Glssymbol{compressor} Air Outlet Mass Flow Rate},
  description={Compressor Air Outlet Mass Flow Rate},
  parent=PQ
}
```

With these "math entries" I want the symbol `\glssymbol{compressor}` in lowercase. But when I use the symbol in the text document, sometimes I will use the `\GLSsymbol` form or `\Glssymbol` or `\glssymbol`. But currently in my MWE the symbol is printed in lowercase in the glossary (off course) but I would prefer a Capitalized or uppercase form and it depends on me (it's a case by case choice). This is why I would prefer a solution with a new field (like `symbolname`) in order to manually choose if I want to print the symbol in capitalisez form (Cp) or uppercase form (CM)...

Comment: +1 Your question is very well formulated and complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (2)** after follow-up question.

There is now a new key-defined symbol name (`symbolname`) that will be used **to print** the glossary. You can use any other "symbol" you want, not just uppercase, as shown in this example.

If `symbolname` is not defined it will be use the `symbol` value to print the glossary. (new) <<

A new entry `compressor_valve` was added to show this default behavior.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\glsaddkey*% 
{symbolname}% key
{\glsentrysymbol{\glslabel}}% default value CHANGED <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\glsentrysymbolname}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentrysymbolname}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glssymbolname}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glssymbolname}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSsymbolname}% command analogous to \GLStext 

 \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \hangindent#1\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent#1\glstreeindent\relax
    \ifnum#1=1\relax
    \glssubentryitem{#2}%
    \fi
    \glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{#2}{\glossentryname{#2}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{#2}{\space(\glsentrysymbolname{#2})}{}%
    \glstreechildpredesc\glossentrydesc{#2}\glspostdescription\space #3\par
}%

% *******************************************

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}   

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={4}}   
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
    name={Compressor},
    text={compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    description={Air Compressor},
    symbol={cp},
    symbolname={\textcolor{red}{123Cpxx}},% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={Compressor Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={compressor motor},
    description={Motor of the \Gls{compressor}},
    symbol={cm},
    symbolname={456CMxx},% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_valve}% symbolname is not defined <<<<<<<<<<<<
{
    name={Compressor Valve},
    sort={compressor valve},
    text={compressor valve},
    description={Valve of the \Gls{compressor}},
    symbol={vv},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{PQ}{name={Physical Quantities},description={\glspar},sort={5}}
\newglossaryentry{Qcp}
{
    name={$\mathbf{\bm{Q}}_{\glssymbol{compressor},out}$},
    sort={Qcpout},
    text={\Glssymbol{compressor} Air Outlet Mass Flow Rate},
    description={Compressor Air Outlet Mass Flow Rate},
    symbol={cp},
    symbolname={FlowRate},% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    parent=PQ
}

\begin{document}
    
    \gls{compressor_valve};
    \gls{compressor_motor};
    \gls{compressor}
    
    \bigskip    
    
    \gls{Qcp}
    
    \printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

**Check** using beamer class

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
```

....

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}       
        \gls{compressor_valve};
        \gls{compressor_motor};
        \gls{compressor}        
        \bigskip    
        
        \gls{Qcp}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Glossary}       
    \printnoidxglossary
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: ab]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exaclty what I asked for ! However, after some tests I wonder If it would be possible to use the "symbol" field by default (to print the glossary) if the "symbolname" field is not declared ?

Comment: @Sylvain Rigal Thank you for your feedback!. Your suggestion improves the code. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot ! And it works if  "symbol" AND "symbolname" fields are not defined ! Just a little remark : a "}" is missing at the end of your code "\end{document" ;) Thank you again, this is exactly what I need !

Comment: @Sylvain Rigal Done! Thank you for your last feedback!

Comment: You put a ")" instead of a "}" ;) Sorry...

Comment: @Sylvain Rigal Not my best day!

Comment: This solution doesn’t work with Beamer class. Do you know by chance how to make it works with Beamer ?

Comment: @ Please try the Updated(2)  answer.

Comment: Just Perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: @Sylvain Rigal Over time it will converge on a very good solution!

Comment: I have a new request sorry! It seems that this code disable the display of all glossary entries with a level upper than 3. That means, only the 3 first levels of the glossary are printed in the glossary print and if I remove your piece of code dealing with the `symbolname` field, then all the glossary levels apears correctly in the glossary print...

Comment: @SylvainRigal I do not understand the issue. Could you please provide an example of the desired output? Perhaps in another question .... ?

Comment: Finally it works perfectly! The problem was that I used an old version of your solution (I don't know why). I found the problem while working on the new question (luckily you offered me to ask a new one!). So I'm sincerely sorry and thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @SylvainRigal I'm glad my insignificant help helped!