# Which one is recommed to use for subscript? T_{\text{yay}} or T_\text{yay}

Tags: formatting, indexing, subscripts

Is there a difference between T_{\text{yay}} and T_\text{yay}?

And is one of the both versions recommed to use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlanMunn technically rather different as omitting braces in `\frac{1}{2}` applies to all macros, but omitting the brace in `_\text{abc}` is very specific to `_` (and `\text`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've removed the close vote then.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Why does `x_\text y` works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175247/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same but the fact that the second one works at all depends on the weird internal parsing of the argument of `_` I  would never use that form. Compare with `\sqrt{\text{yay}}` which works and `\sqrt\text{yay}` that does not.  Normally (unless it is really a text phrase) I would use `\mathrm` rather than `\text`

Comment: And what about \symup? For me, they all seem to do the same. Is it just for easier to read LaTex-Code?

Comment: @julandi `\symup` is unicode-math package, `\text` makes text using your documents surrounding text font (spaces make spaces and it will be italic if surrounding text is)  `\mathrm` is  math mode and always uses a fixed font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but `$\x_{text{mín}}$` works, and `$\x_{mathrm{mín}}$` fails... (notice the accented i (*í* ) in the subscript) (utf8 inputenc and T1 fontenc correctly loaded, of course)...

Comment: @Rmano accented letters in math are usually avoided as they clash with diacritics used as math operators, but if you are using a language where they are needed you could set up `\mathrm` to use a T1 encoded font of course