# How to work the below equations in tex4ht/make4ht

Tags: pdftex, tex4ht

I have very very simple equations. It's working well in PdfLaTeX and not working in tex4ht.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\begin{document}
$K^\mathrm{mno}$
\end{document}
```

I know before superscript need to give `{`. But it's working fine in PdfLaTeX and why not working in tex4ht/make4ht. Not only "^"(superscript) "_" also not working.

How to do i need to work in tex4ht/make4ht? Any great help is highly appreciate.

I have need to achive in **simple cfg** file and find it below:

```
\Configure{ext}{xhtml}
\Preamble{xhtml,html5,mathml,NLM,charset=UTF-8,-xtpipes,NoFonts,refcaption,ext=.xhtml}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\begin{document} 
\renewcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\renewcommand{\mathrm}{<br/><br/>}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: `K^\mathrm{mno}` is wrong syntax. That it works in pdflatex is luck, but as you see you are not so lucky with tex4ht. Use the right input syntax `K^{\mathrm{mno}}`.

Comment: @Ulrike: I have known that. But i would like to do automatically this point using config file. How to give "^" and "_" braces automatic process. Kindly advise. Pdflatex concept will not work in our tex4ht?

Comment: Or we can modify old latex command to new latex command. So that i will try above my point in this format. for example ^\mathrm need to change ^\bmathrm.

Comment: Wasn't I clear? Use the right input syntax. It only works in pdflatex because of some special points of the internal processing, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175247/why-does-x-text-y-work/175256#175256. It doesn't make sense to add some complicated code to tex4ht only because you are too lazy to input two braces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Ulrike solved it in the comments

Comment: `TeX4ht` works purely based on correct format of `LaTeX` tagging method and you should follow it without excuse, as `Ulrike` mentioned you should correct your tagging

Comment: at last questions how to configure mathbf to bold "\Configure{mathbf}{\HCode{<br/><bold>}\NoFonts}{\HCode{</bold>}\EndNoFonts}". This syntax is correct or not...